# Emojis in Salesforce Community is not working

Tags: community

I am trying to create content using the rich content editor in Salesforce Community and when submitting the content and publish the page the emoji's in the content are working fine. But when I view the published page it's broken. Not sure if I need to change any encoding setting in the community. I tried even using Html Editor.

[image]

Comment: On trying some more emoji's found few them of work while some does not. EX: <p>I will display &#8986;</p> <p>I will display &#x231A;</p> WORKS. But <p>I will display &#127752;</p> <p>I will display &#x1F308;</p> DOES NOT WORK. I have updated the meta tag for the page to <meta charset="UTF-8">